# Разделить строку пробелом в зависимости от написания

Tags: c#

Нужно добавлять пробел если строка без пробела.
Например несколько строк встречающихся в одном и том же файле:

```
1. 22мкФ
2. 20 мкФ
3. 10пФ
4. 3,3 кОм
5. 100Ом
```

Суть в том, что нужно добавить пробел между цифрой и буквой в случае если пробела нет. То есть в итоге должно получиться так:

```
1. 22 мкФ
2. 20 мкФ
3. 10 пФ
4. 3,3 кОм
5. 100 Ом
```

Я попытался найти индекс первого вхождения буквы и добавлять пробел перед ней, но почему-то пробел не добавляется.

```
int indx = CmpntLst[i].getValue().IndexOf(Regex.Match(CmpntLst[i].getValue(), @"[A-Za-zА-Яа-я]").Value);
    CmpntLst[i].setValue(CmpntLst[i].getValue().Insert(indx, " "));
```

Да и это не решит проблему если пробел есть, получится второй пробел...

Comment: Возможно это регулярное выражение вам больше поможет: (\d+)(\s)?([A-Za-zА-Яа-я]+)$, а потом простая замены на группы 1 и 3, а между ними пробел. Код например можно такой использовать: `Regex.Replace(lineFromFile, @"(\d+)(\s)?([A-Za-zА-Яа-я]+)$", "$1 $3");`

Comment: `CmpntLst[i].setValue(Regex.Replace(CmpntLst[i].getValue(), "(?<=\d)(?=\p{L})", " "));`

Comment: А можно расшифровать "(?<=\d)(?=\p{L})"? Потому как оно сработало как надо. Хотя я уже нашел на msdn) Спасибо за рабочий код)

Answer (score 3):

Можно так:

```
var rgx = new Regex(@"(\d+\. )([\d\,]+)([А-Яа-я]+)");
var result = new List<string>();
foreach (var str in CmpntLst)
{
    var x = rgx.Match(str);
    result.Add(x.Success ? string.Format("{0}{1} {2}", x.Groups[1], x.Groups[2], x.Groups[3]) : str);
}
```

Можно веселее:

```
var rgx = new Regex(@"(\d+\. )([\d\,]+)([А-Яа-я]+)");
var result = (from str in CmpntLst let x = rgx.Match(str) select x.Success ? string.Format("{0}{1} {2}", x.Groups[1], x.Groups[2], x.Groups[3]) : str).ToList();
```

Или даже так:

```
var rgx = new Regex(@"([\d\,]+)\s?([А-Яа-я]+)");
var result = CmpntLst
    .Select((x,i) => new { num=i+1, match = rgx.Match(x)})
    .Select(d => $"{d.num}. {d.match.Groups[1]} {d.match.Groups[2]}")
    .ToList();
```